# file (image) wouldn't upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload images in a if/elseif statement. I passed the $_FILES as a function parameter, since the print_r outputs array()I think the passing worked. Or is there something wrong in the logic I create? Would anyone please pinpoint it out? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
    require_once('../resources/library/admin.class.php');
    $obj_admin = new admin();
    echo $obj_admin->product_list;
    echo '<h1>inventory list</h1></br>';
    $obj_admin->displayList();
    $obj_admin->editData();
    $obj_admin->deleteData();

                            $add[] = '<form name="invent" method="post" action="index.php?res=resources&adm=admin&page=inventory.php" class="ínvent">';
                                    $add[] = '<fieldset>';
                                        $add[] = '<legend>Add products</legend>';
                                            $add[] = "<label for='name'>name</label>";
                                            $add[] = "<input type='text' name='user' value='Grachten' />";
                                        $add[] = '</br>';
                                            $add[] = "<label for='price'>price</label>";
                                            $add[] = "<input type='number' name='price' value='150'  />";
                                        $add[] = '</br>';
                                            $add[] = "<label for='description'>description</label>";
                                            $add[] = "<textarea name='description' rows='10' cols= '80'>Its the best!</textarea>";
                                        $add[] = '</br>';
                                            $add[] = "<label for='img'>img</label>";
                                            $add[] = "<input name='image' accept='image/jpeg' type='file' value='files'>";
                                        $add[] = '</br>';
                                        $add[] ="<input type='submit' name='submit'/>";
                                    $add[] = '</fieldset>';
                                    $add[] = '</form>';
                                    echo implode($add);

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['user'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
                   $obj_admin->addData($name, $price, $description, $_FILES);


    }
```

```
    function addData($name, $price, $description, $files)
                    {

                                    if(!empty($name) || !empty($price) || !empty($description))
                                    {
                                           if($sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name= ? LIMIT 1"))
                                            {
                                                $sql->bind_param('s', $name);
                                                $sql->execute();
                                                $sql->store_result();
                                                $sql->fetch();
                                                $numrows = $sql->num_rows;
                                                print_r($numrows);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                echo "something is wrong";
                                            }
                                            if($numrows>0)
                                            {
                                                        echo 'duplicate, go to <a href="index.php?res=resources&adm=admin&page=inventory.php">same page</a>';
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                if($insert = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO products (name, price, description) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"))
                                                {

                                                            $insert->bind_param('sds', $name, $price, $description);
                                                            $insert->execute();
                                                }
                                                //The uploaden image is sent to temp map
                                                elseif(isset($files['image']['size'])<=2048000)
                                                {

                                                    if ($files["image"]["error"] > 0)
                                                    {
                                                            echo "Return Code: " . $files["image"]["error"] . "<br />";
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                            $uploaddir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/webshop/public/img/content";
                                                            $moved = move_uploaded_file($files['image']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir/$files['image']);
                                                            if($moved)
                                                            {
                                                                echo "succes";
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                echo "failure";
                                                            }
                                                    }

                                                        //Shows where its stored
                                                        echo "Stored in: " . "C:/xampp/htdocs/webshop/public/img/content/" . $files["file"]["name"];


                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                            echo "didnt inserted the damn thing!";
                                                }
                                            }

                                        }

                                        print_r($files);

                            }
```

Comment: So much code... make it simple for the question. People won't do all the work for you.

Comment: This needs basic debugging, it's not something we can do for you. Is `$_FILES` present and populated in the first place?

Comment: I agree with most others here:  Strip out all the other code and just try to see if your $_FILES var contains data on form submit.  If so, try to upload, if that works, then try adding back in your database stuff so you can see what exactly is holding up the process.  Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form tag, you could check if that was the issue by var_dump($_FILES) which in your case will be empty

Answer (score 0):

Add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your `<form>` tag.

This allows files to be included as part of the form data, the lack of this is most likely why `$_FILES` is empty.